# different background color to bottom navigation tab selected item by using material design

Tags: android, material-design, android-bottomnav

I want to implement background color of selected item like below in the image

[image]

but unfortunately everyone are trying to answer this using some third party library.

I want to achieve this with material design component itself

this is my code

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/id_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_style"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_style"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu_items" />
```

style.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_selected="false" />

</selector>
```

Whether it can be achieved or not with material design component only, just tell me in answer.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Some curious thing i found is you cannot have background color and text/icon color style on same file.

so u need two files

bottom_navigation_style.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_selected="false" />

</selector>
```

bottom_navigation_style_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="false" />

</selector>
```

Then on activity xml you need to add to itemBackground like this

```
 app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_navigation_style_background"
 app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_style"
 app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_style"
```

It will work for sure.

Comment: Ok, because of lack of information on other answer i failed to achieve this. Anyhow thank you for detailed answer

Answer (score 3):

Please try one this, In bottom navigation view give a property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/id_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/drwable_value_selected"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drwable_value_selected"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

app:itemBackground

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/dark" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
```

Check your menu items

```
    <item
     android:id="@+id/action_message"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

checkable true is must for select and unselect background color.

[image]

Comment: didn't worked for me. Kindly check yourself and if it worked for you then post it as answer.